# Storing Recordset to Array in VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, recordset

I have a dynamic function to call a stored procedure and store the recordset in an array, which I want to use in another sub. But I don't get the result in an array like this:

```
Array(0,0) = 1
Array(0,1) = Miller
Array(1,0) = 2
Array(1,1) = Jones
Array(2,0) = 3
Array(2,1) = Jackson
....
```

My Array result is like this:

```
Array(0,0) = 1
Array(1,0) = Miller
Array(0,1) = 2
Array(1,1) = Jones
Array(0,2) = 3
Array(1,2) = Jackson
....
```

To understand the process I'm showing you the `SQL-statement`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetAllPersons
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT u.ID, u.Name
    FROM dbo.v_Users u
END
GO
```

The function to get the recordset and store it in an array:

```
Public Function fGetDataBySProc(ByVal sProcName As String) As Variant
    ...
    
    Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
    With Cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandText = sProcName
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    End With
    
    Dim ObjRs As New ADODB.Recordset: Set ObjRs = Cmd.Execute
    Dim ArrData() As Variant
    
    If Not ObjRs.EOF Then
        ArrData = ObjRs.GetRows(ObjRs.RecordCount)
    End If
    
    ObjRs.Close
    cn.Close
    
    fGetDataBySProc = ArrData
End Function
```

The sub where the function is called:

```
Public Sub cbFillPersons()
    Dim sProcString As String: sProcString = "dbo.sp_GetAllPersons"
    Dim ArrData As Variant: ArrData = fGetDataBySProc(sProcString)   
    Dim i as Integer
    
    ' Just for testing
    For i = LBound(ArrData) To UBound(ArrData)
        Debug.Print "AddItem: " & ArrData(0, i)
        Debug.Print "List: " & ArrData(1, i)
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't know, what I'm doing wrong. Maybe it is the `.GetRows()`-method?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just do a Power Query into the SQL db??? Using VBA for this is so 2003.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong as such: this is just how GetRows() works.  It returns a 2D array with dimensions (1 to #ofColumns, 1 to #ofRows).  You can still use that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Transpose 2D Array

- You could transpose your resulting array using the `getTransposedArray` function.
- Then the last line in your `fGetDataBySProc` function would be:

  ```
   fGetDataBySProc = getTransposedArray(ArrData)
  ```

**The Function**

```
Function getTransposedArray(Data As Variant) _
         As Variant
    
    Dim LB2 As Long
    LB2 = LBound(Data, 2)
    Dim UB2 As Long
    UB2 = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(LB2 To UB2, LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1))
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        For j = LB2 To UB2
            Result(j, i) = Data(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    getTransposedArray = Result
                 
End Function
```