# VBA: How do I merge several columns into 1 ? My current code works but only <450 rows

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function

I would like some guidance, I am trying to merge multiple columns into 1 (see screenshot).

I was wondering if someone please could help me understand why the function below stops working after about 450 rows ? I need it to go up to 10000 rows.

And possibly a better way to do this?

Column `BZ` and `CA` (yellow) contains the array formula :

`BZ =MergeRanges(P3:P10000;R3:R10000;T3:T10000;V3:V10000;X3:X10000;Z3:Z10000;AB3:AB10000;AD3:AD10000;AF3:AF10000;AH3:AH10000;AJ3:AJ10000;AL3:AL10000;AN3:AN10000;AP3:AP10000;AR3:AR10000;AT3:AT10000;AV3:AV10000;AX3:AX10000;AZ3:AZ10000;BB3:BB10000;BD3:BD10000;BF3:BF10000;BH3:BH10000;BJ3:BJ10000;BL3:BL10000;BN3:BN10000;BP3:BP10000;BR3:BR10000;BT3:BT10000;BV3:BV10000;BX3:BX10000)`

`CA =MergeRanges(Q3:Q10000;S3:S10000;U3:U10000;W3:W10000;Y3:Y10000;AA3:AA10000;AC3:AC10000;AE3:AE10000;AG3:AG10000;AI3:AI10000;AK3:AK10000;AM3:AM10000;AO3:AO10000;AQ3:AQ10000;AS3:AS10000;AU3:AU10000;AW3:AW10000;AY3:AY10000;BA3:BA10000;BC3:BC10000;BE3:BE10000;BG3:BG10000;BI3:BI10000;BK3:BK10000;BM3:BM10000;BO3:BO10000;BQ3:BQ10000;BS3:BS10000;BU3:BU10000;BW3:BW10000;BY3:BY10000)`

VBA

```
Function MergeRanges(ParamArray arguments() As Variant) As Variant()
Dim cell As Range, temp() As Variant
ReDim temp(0)

For Each argument In arguments
  For Each cell In argument
    If cell <> "" Then
      temp(UBound(temp)) = cell
      ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
    End If
  Next cell
Next argument

ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) - 1)
MergeRanges = Application.Transpose(temp)

End Function
```

Thanks a lot

[image: excel capture]

**EDIT**

I found a way to make it work without a function. See example below but with only 6 columns to simplify. However, as my actual purpose requires 31x2 rows, I need to repeat the example below into 62 lines. So it is loooooong and ugly.

```
Sub StackEm1()

Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("H3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("C3:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
Range("E3:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Call StackEm2

End Sub

Sub StackEm2()

Range("B3:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("I3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("D3:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
Range("F3:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Result

[image]

Comment: `Application.Transpose` has a limit of `65535` elements per dimension. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418682/storing-recordset-to-array-in-vba/64418935#64418935) is a function that will allow you to transpose without limitations.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you! I am sorry, I am still very much a VBA beginner, could you please advice a bit further exactly what I need to do?

Comment: The beginning of  your function is missing so I cannot know what it is supposed to do. If your function is failing due to the reason mentioned in my first comment, you can copy the function provided in the link to the same place where your function is located. Then in the last line of your function use: `MergeRanges = getTransposedArray(temp)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I am sorry, I updated it. The new function provided does not work for me. 
I am maybe not doing it right. But now I know it is because Application.Transpose 
has limited elements so I will find another way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Get Stacked Columns

**Excel Formula**

- You can use the following formula to get the desired result:

  ```
  =INDEX(P$3:BX$10000,MOD(ROW()-3,9998)+1,2*INT((ROW()-3)/9998)+1)
  ```

  Use the formula in cell `BZ3` and copy down to `CA309940`.
  Use common logic if the values are different, e.g. 9998 = 10000 - 3 + 1 ...etc.

  For the posted image the formula would be:

  ```
  =INDEX(P$3:BX$32,MOD(ROW()-3,30)+1,2*INT((ROW()-3)/30)+1)
  ```

**VBA**

The code consists of three procedures:

- The first is the `getStackedColumns` function, the 'star of the show'.
- The second is a simple test with a small amount of data with which you can easily learn what the function exactly does.
- The third is a practical (hard coded, simplified for the `ActiveSheet`) example which you can run to get the data into the appropriate two ranges (columns). It took 3 seconds (without any caluclations) on my machine, which makes me wonder that if you would put a formula into every cell in those columns, how (in)efficient this would become (309938 cells per column).

**The Code**

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values of mulitple given ranges, by column,
'               to a 2D one-based one-column array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getStackedColumns(ParamArray Ranges() As Variant) _
         As Variant
    
' Ranges() - 'Ranges Array'
' Each element of 'Ranges Array' - 'current Source Range'
' Sources - 'Sources Array' (a jagged array of arrays)
' Each element of 'Sources Array' - 'current Source Array'
    
' Initialize error handling.
    
    Const ProcName As String = "getStackedColumns"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
' Write values from Ranges Array to Sources Array.
    
    ' Validate Ranges Array: check if there are any elements.
    If UBound(Ranges) < LBound(Ranges) Then
        GoTo NoElements
    End If
    
    ' Define Sources Array, resize it to the size or Ranges Array.
    Dim Sources As Variant
    ReDim Sources(1 To UBound(Ranges) - LBound(Ranges) + 1)
    
    ' Define One-Cell Array to help when a range contains one cell only.
    Dim OneCell As Variant
    ReDim OneCell(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare variables for upcoming 'For Each Next' loop.
    Dim rng As Variant  ' Current (Source Range) Element in Ranges Array
    Dim tRows As Long   ' Target (Array) Number of Rows
    Dim rCount As Long  ' Current Source Rows Count
    Dim cCount As Long  ' Current Source Columns Count
    Dim sCount As Long  ' Subscript of Current Source Array
    
    ' Loop through (iterate) elements (ranges) in Ranges Array.
    For Each rng In Ranges
        ' Validate current Source Range in Ranges Array.
        If TypeName(rng) = "Range" Then
            ' Define subscript of current Source Array.
            sCount = sCount + 1
            ' Define number of rows in current Source Range.
            rCount = rng.Rows.Count
            ' Define number of columns in current Source Range.
            cCount = rng.Columns.Count
            ' Check if there is more than one cell in current Source Range.
            If rCount > 1 Or cCount > 1 Then
                ' Write values from current Source Range
                ' to current Source Array.
                Sources(sCount) = rng.Value
            Else
                ' Copy One-Cell Array, which is becoming current Source Array,
                ' to Sources Array.
                Sources(sCount) = OneCell
                ' Write the only value in current Source (Cell) Range
                ' to the only element of current Source Array.
                Sources(sCount)(1, 1) = rng.Value
            End If
            ' Add the product of current Source Arrays rows and columns
            ' to Target Number of Rows.
            tRows = tRows + rCount * cCount
        End If
    Next rng
    
    ' Validate Sources Array: check if there are any elements.
    If sCount = 0 Then
        GoTo NoRanges
    End If
    
' Write values from arrays of Sources Array to Target Array.
    
    ' Define Target Array.
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To tRows, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare counter variables (counters) for the upcoming 'For Next' loop.
    Dim sCol As Long ' Source Column Counter (Current Column in Source Array)
    Dim sRow As Long ' Source Row Counter (Current Row in Source Array)
    Dim tRow As Long ' Target Row Counter (Current Row in Target Array)
    
    ' Loop through (iterate) Source Arrays (of Sources Array).
    For sCount = 1 To sCount
        ' Loop through (iterate) columns of current Source Array.
        For sCol = 1 To UBound(Sources(sCount), 2)
            ' Loop through (iterate) rows of current Source Array.
            For sRow = 1 To UBound(Sources(sCount), 1)
                ' Define current row of Target array.
                tRow = tRow + 1
                ' Write value from current element of Source Array
                ' to current element of Target Array.
                Target(tRow, 1) = Sources(sCount)(sRow, sCol)
            Next sRow
        Next sCol
    Next sCount
    
' Write result and exit (Success).
    
    getStackedColumns = Target
    GoTo ProcExit

' Labels (Fail)

NoElements:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No elements found."
    GoTo ProcExit

NoRanges:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No ranges found."
    GoTo ProcExit

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

' Exit

ProcExit:

End Function

Sub testGetStackedColumnRanges()
    
    ' Test No Elements.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = getStackedColumns()
    ' There is no result. Data is empty. The message in the Immediate window is:
    ' 'getStackedColumns': No elements found.

    ' Test No Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Data = getStackedColumns(rng) ' rng is Nothing.
    ' There is no result. Data is empty. The message in the Immediate window is:
    ' 'getStackedColumns': No ranges found.
    
    ' Test with bad inputs.
    Data = getStackedColumns([A1], , 1.12, 13, [B1:B2], True, Nothing, [C1:D2])
    If Not IsEmpty(Data) Then
        Dim tRow As Long
        For tRow = 1 To UBound(Data)
            Debug.Print Data(tRow, 1)
        Next tRow
    End If
    ' The result are the values from the following cells:
    '  A1
    '  B1
    '  B2
    '  C1
    '  C2
    '  D1
    '  D2

End Sub

Sub writeStackedColumns()
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To 2)
    
    Data(1) = getStackedColumns([P3:P10000], [R3:R10000], [T3:T10000], _
                                [V3:V10000], [X3:X10000], [Z3:Z10000], _
                                [AB3:AB10000], [AD3:AD10000], [AF3:AF10000], _
                                [AH3:AH10000], [AJ3:AJ10000], [AL3:AL10000], _
                                [AN3:AN10000], [AP3:AP10000], [AR3:AR10000], _
                                [AT3:AT10000], [AV3:AV10000], [AX3:AX10000], _
                                [AZ3:AZ10000], [BB3:BB10000], [BD3:BD10000], _
                                [BF3:BF10000], [BH3:BH10000], [BJ3:BJ10000], _
                                [BL3:BL10000], [BN3:BN10000], [BP3:BP10000], _
                                [BR3:BR10000], [BT3:BT10000], [BV3:BV10000], _
                                [BX3:BX10000])
    
    Data(2) = getStackedColumns([Q3:Q10000], [S3:S10000], [U3:U10000], _
                                [W3:W10000], [Y3:Y10000], [AA3:AA10000], _
                                [AC3:AC10000], [AE3:AE10000], [AG3:AG10000], _
                                [AI3:AI10000], [AK3:AK10000], [AM3:AM10000], _
                                [AO3:AO10000], [AQ3:AQ10000], [AS3:AS10000], _
                                [AU3:AU10000], [AW3:AW10000], [AY3:AY10000], _
                                [BA3:BA10000], [BC3:BC10000], [BE3:BE10000], _
                                [BG3:BG10000], [BI3:BI10000], [BK3:BK10000], _
                                [BM3:BM10000], [BO3:BO10000], [BQ3:BQ10000], _
                                [BS3:BS10000], [BU3:BU10000], [BW3:BW10000], _
                                [BY3:BY10000])
    
    [BZ3].Resize(UBound(Data(1))).Value = Data(1)
    [CA3].Resize(UBound(Data(2))).Value = Data(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! However I only get the first column with the code above, column P in BZ and column Q in CA. So it does not get stacked. I am trying to figure out what is missing.